# Why the pinout on the Raspberry Pi Pico development board, are labeled under the board?

Tags: development-tools, raspberry-pi-pico

It may seem a stupid question, because it is common for many careless manufacturers to print the pin markings under a development board; but not for a company which is known for its user friendly designs and a big audience in maker and hobbyist communities.

When installed on a breadboard (which is intended use for same form-factor dev-boards), the labels are underneath the board. without a pin-out card or picture available at hand, we have to remove and find a pin and put it back on the breadboard. even for a permanent use, (soldering it on a motherboard), it would make the troubleshooting harder.

The PCB itself doesn't seem very tight. a little reordering of graphics or parts would make it possible:

[image: the RPi pico board]

Is there any specific reason for that? or it's just because the designer forgot to pay much attention to details?

Comment: why are you asking here? ... we are not mindreaders ...  it seems to me that you should be asking the manufacturer why they made this choice

Comment: @jsotola Is it not possible that there's a convention OP is not aware of that experts here might know?

Comment: @Bort, yes it is possible ... if you think about it logically, even if you know nothing about electronics, the issue is one of two things ... either the board is meant to be used upside down or on its edge, or the designer did not think of usability of the product ... the simplest conclusion is the design related one

Comment: now that i said that, i thought of a reason ... it is quite possibly invalid ... the board is meant to be used as a component in devices ... lot of times, sensors and actuators would be connected by soldering wires directly to the board ... the wire end would be pushed from front and soldered from the back ... the board would be oriented upside down when attaching wires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a good design question.

Rookie designer maybe.

The only thing one could move alot is the button, but I guess they wanted it close to the USB port.

Notice how far away L is from Data+- and the trace width for low impedance. That’s important.

Look how close the DCDC converter is to the input. That too is important not to share ground noise.

They could have gone to under-sized font for the print screen of epoxy paint but risk smearing or gaps.

I would have gone for thinner Data tracks (lower L/C) with thin guard grounds on either side to make room for screened pin labels. Then the dielectric gap might have to decrease to raise C and match the increased L to maintain L/C ratio, which compromises stiffness. It’s possible with fine line coplanar capacitance to raise C but not as much as gap to parallel bottom side gnd.

So an extra mm or more to fit the screen print is possible for both sides and the logo is definitely oversized.

What would you do differently and maintain CMRR and trace impedance?

Also a lot of users longish mismatched cable impedances with ringing: and with 25 Ohm driver impedance, they could put shorted pads for 603 series resistors to match the high cable impedances and reduce ringing with a cut and place 220 to 300 Ohm R.

Comment: I see. So the answer is ***engineering trade off***. Thank you very much for your professional lecture on PCB design. Me hobbyist PCB designer only knew how to use home use paint and brush to paint the mask for traces, but I forgot how to remove the non trace copper. It was more than 20 years ago that I did my last PCB fabrication (when I never heard of something called a real home use or hobbyist use breadboard). Nowadays I would ask "***the purple PCB guy O'Park*** to do that for me.

Comment: I haven’t done board layouts for 44 years,by hand  when I would do 3 a week with > 30 IC’s in one month but since I learnt how tell the good, from the best and understand RF improvements.